# Cannot Create Table in PgAdmin

Tags: sql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

All of a sudden, pgadmin will not let me create a table. I keep getting a syntax error. I have even tried to run create table commands that have worked in the past and now they cause the same error. Did something change in PgAdmin?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
CREATE TABLE food
(
    "meat" text,
    "veggies" text
)
```

And here is the error I get:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "text"
> LINE 2:  "meat" text,
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 154

What is going on?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. I ran it successfully in PgAdmin 4. Maybe the error is due to the version of postgres. I used version 14.1.

Comment: Also, can you put the table name in quotes and try again?

Comment: The error is coming from PostgreSQL. pgAdmin has nothing to do with this. I tried on PostgreSQL 12 and it works fine.

Comment: been there done that. this happens when you click "explain" and not "execute"